# Automate UWP Camera app

Tags: python-2.7, automation, uwp, windows-10, pywinauto

I want to automate UWP Camera app of Windows 10 using python. I am able to launch the app but after that I am not able to click on capture button as I am not getting handler for it.

```
import subprocess
from pywinauto import Desktop, Application
import time sp = subprocess.call("start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App",‌​shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
app = Application().connect(title_re = ".*Camera", class_name = "ApplicationFrameWindow")

# When I do this, I get an error that app doesn't have a child window.
app.child_window(auto_id="CaptureButton_0").invoke()
```

Comment: What did you try? Please add more details to your question so that we can help. Can we download this app? Which code did you run? What is the output? Did you read the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) first?

Comment: In windows 10, it is an inbuilt app. I assume you know about UWP/Metro app. I will attach my code for more clarity. 

import subprocess
from pywinauto import Desktop,Application
import time

sp = subprocess.call("start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCamera_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App",shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
app = Application().connect(title_re = ".*Camera", class_name = "ApplicationFrameWindow")
app.child_window(auto_id="CaptureButton_0").invoke()

# When I do this, I get an error that app doesn't have a child window.

Comment: For UWP app you need to use `Application(backend='uia')`. Please read the docs by the link I posted in previous comment. It explains a lot of useful things.